# get a word between two single quotes using bash script

Tags: bash

I have a string like this code `GET="start from '12345' and continue"` now what i wanted to do is extract the value between the single quotes from the variable GET and store them on a variable using bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `read` with custom `IFS`:

```
GET="start from '12345' and continue"

IFS="'" read _ b _ <<< "$GET"
echo "$b"
12345
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
GET="start from '12345' and continue" 
value=${GET#*\'}
value=${value%\'*}
echo $value
```

Or, use an array and $IFS:

```
value=$(
    IFS=\'
    arr=($GET)
    echo ${arr[1]}
    )
echo $value
```

Answer (score 0):

Many things will work here. Try:
`echo $GET | grep -o \'.*\'`
Gives the exact content matching between two single quotes. If you want to store this in a variable:
`myvar=$(echo $GET | grep -o \'.*\')`

Answer (score 0):

As no-one has yet mentioned it, another possibility would be to use bash regular expressions:

```
$ re="'([^']*)'"
$ [[ $GET =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
12345
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to avoid bashism (i.e. to make POSIX shell), you may use sed :

```
echo "$GET" | sed -n " s,[^']*'\([^']*\).*,\1,p "
12345
```

(BTW my preferred solution is the one from Tom Fenech)